# will uri change every time an app is restarted in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I want to develop a windows phone app that makes use of push notification. I know that first thing my app should do is to register to mspn and get uri. My doubt it that , will the uri keep changing every time the app get closed and then start again.

Answer (score 2):

The notification URL should* stay static across restarts of your app.

*other factors may come into play, for example uninstalling and re-installing will probably result in a change.

Answer (score 2):

It should stay the same if you open/close your app. I've had an app using push notifications on the marketplace for a few months now and my URI for it hasn't changed. I'd follow [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202967%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and subscribe to the `ChannelUriUpdated` event just in case the channel does change (I'm unaware of the reasons why it would change however):

```
// Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);


void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
{
    // e.ChannelUri contains your updated notification channel - you can pass this to your web service
}
```

Comment: There are lots of things which could force it to change but no published, definitive, list.